# Is there a standard or pre-built inventory management for products in B2B commerce?

Tags: omnichannel, commerce-cloud, b2b-commerce, b2b, cloudcraze

I have set up a store and integrated a checkout flow. But there doesn't seem to be a standard quantity field on the product or any available inventory object to calculate the product quantity. Am I missing something? Or does Salesforce not really provide that option yet?
I realize there is something called Omnichannel inventory, do I need a license for it? Because I'm unable to enable it.
Could someone direct me in the right way?

I want to be able to have a quantity field on my products/warehouse, etc., so that if there are only 5 units of that product available in my inventory, then the customer cannot order for more than 5 units of that product.

Is there a standard feature available for this? Or do I have to customize this process?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.